# IOS: Detect swipe gestures in a specific place on a UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uistoryboard

I am creating a storyboard app where the view is changed when the user performs swipe gestures.  The issue I am having is that when you drag and drop a gesture recognizer onto the view from the`main.storyboard` file, the gesture is recognized from anywhere inside the UIView.  Basically, I need to recognize a gesture that is performed in a specific area on the screen, similar to how you drag down the notification center in IOS 6.  If this is unclear or you need more details, feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure if this will help you or you tried something like this, but i want to share my idea.

You can try UISwipeGestureRecognizer in your ViewControl.m like below:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeToDoMethod)];
[swipeGesture setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
[[self innerView] addGestureRecognizer: swipeGesture];
```

You can add an inner view into your main view and add this gesture to that view.

Hope this helps you, good luck! :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  This seems like a good idea, but where in this code  is the location of the inner view set?  Also, how can I get my main view to switch using storyboards after the swipe is performed.  Thanks for any further help

Comment: I mentioned inner view as your specific area. So you need to add a new UIView into your main view. I could understand your second question. If you mean that you want to switch main view after swipe gesture in the inner view, I can suggest two things. One is your inner view is a part of your view so you do not need to switch any view. Or if you apply this to another view, you should write a method which I called "swipeToDoMethod" in the above code. You should set visibilities of the views to by using
[someView setHidden:YES];
[anotherView setHidden:NO];
I hope these are clear answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(SwipeView)];
[swipe setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[[self innerView] addGestureRecognizer: swipe];
```

//UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight (or) up (or) down

Answer (score 0):

Use another UIView with 0 visibility, put it on area where you want recognize a gesture and then add gesture to this UIView.

This is just an idea.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a subview into your view, set the subview's frame to the area where you want to catch the swipe gesture, add recognizer to it, and set its background color to clear color. Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Swift version:

```
//Add gesture recognizer
let swipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissShowMessageAndButtonDueToSwipeUp))
swipeGesture.direction = .up
backgroundView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)
```